# Server died in power outage - now won't boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I've recently set up Ubuntu Server on an old machine I had around the house.

It worked really well and I even got it hooked up to a domain I had, but as I was only toying around with the idea of running a home server, I didn't get a UPS for it.

So recently we had a power cut when the machine was running, and now it won't boot.

I usually access it via SSH, and so I don't have a monitor attached to it, but I managed to find one and connect it up, but unfortunately there is no output when I turned it on.

When I turn it on, I get a repeated internal beeping from the machine - but no display whatsoever. - After it makes the normal sounds it would when turned on, the machine idles, but I cannot access anything (no display, not on the network).

It's just a guess but the internal beeping is likely to mean a hardware fault, right? - Especially as it happened after the power was interrupted.

If anyone has any ideas as to what I can try - that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the beep codes are there for a reason!  they tell you whats wrong.  The best thing to do is check the computer manufacturers website, however you didnt provide that info.

Check [this](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm) out though, it will give you an idea.

Comment: My BIOS is Award BIOS - the beeps last for about 1.5 seconds with about 5/6 second intervals - I believe the motherboard is aOpen... I don't know if that's any help.

Comment: Ah just saw the link you pointed to said "Any other beeps" > "RAM problems" for Award BIOS... guess it looks like new ram then? - But could a power cut really break your RAM??

Comment: Well, according to the link I gave you anything other than a 1 long and 2 short is a RAM issue.  Try removing different sticks of RAM or replacing them (if you have known good ones).

Comment: A power cut can break your RAM, PSU and burn pretty much anything in your computer. So yes, very possible. :(

Comment: Oh dear :( I guess the fact that it indicates a RAM issue doesn't mean  that it is a RAM issue either - I mean it could have fried the motherboard or something which is reporting dead RAM?

Comment: Should be a RAM issue. Only RAM and video problem are reported by Beeps, other problems should be reported by BIOS at boot. If the motherboard was gone, it wouldn't turn on.